# Как правильно организовать систему лайков в приложении Android?

Tags: android, база-данных, like

Приветствую, подскажите пожалуйста как правильно организовать систему лайков в приложении. Приложение работает по rest-api с сервера подтягивает данные, а потом  выводит эти записи в виде списка карточек, на каждой карточке есть лайк, сам подсчет организовал, но мне нужно как то хранить инфу, лайкнул ли запись пользователь или нет. В распоряжении есть id записи и токен, как мне хранить такую информацию? Я думаю в БД(Тогда как будет выглядеть такая таблица, придется хранить список в поле с id записи для каждого токена и при необходимости его обновлять?) или же есть другие более гуманные методы?
Все данные хранятся на сервере.

Comment: данные у вас хранятся на сервере?

Comment: хранить список в поле с id записи id юзера, не надо поля использовать не по их прямому назначению

Comment: Используйте SharedPreferences. Ключом будет Id записи, значением true/false (лайкнул/не лайкнул)

Comment: Да, все хранится на сервере. Идея в том что есть токен, есть запись которую может пользователь(токен) лайкнуть один раз

Comment: SharedPreferences будет хранить данные только до тех пора кэш приложения не почистят или не удалят приложение и потом пользователь снова сможет лайкать записи.

Comment: Ну так мы подразумеваем, что когда очиститься кэш, данные придётся подгрузить снова вместе с информацией (лайкнул/не лайкнул).

Comment: Когда приложение удаляется, от БД тоже ничего не остаётся, странная у вас система лайков без бэкэнда)

Comment: Дамир, как раз с Бэкэндом

Comment: Я понял что вы хотите, и андроид здесь не при чем. Как организовать хранение лайков на сервере? Храните отдельно. По id поста получайте количество лайков и список токенов тех, кто лайкнул. Когда получаете запись с бэкэнда, передавайте с get запросом токен пользователя и возвращайте в ответе true если этот токен в списке лайкнувших. Потом, если надо получить список всех тех, кто лайкнул можно сделать отдельный запрос.